# IOException - Cannot load file

Tags: android, file-io, ioexception

I have an app that shows GIF images. *It all works fine if image is saved in drawable*, and I access it like this

```
is=context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.mygif);
movie = Movie.decodeStream(is);
```

But I need to download image from internet, so I'm saving it to CacheDir, that works fine. I tried the following to read it.

```
    try
    {
        is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(context.getCacheDir(), "mygif.gif")));
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    movie = Movie.decodeStream(is);
```

And this

```
movie = Movie.decodeFile(new File(context.getCacheDir(), "mygif.gif").getPath());
```

But no matter what, it ends with

```
java.io.IOException
at java.io.InputStream.reset(InputStream.java:218)
at android.graphics.Movie.decodeStream(Native Method)
at android.graphics.Movie.decodeTempStream(Movie.java:74)
at android.graphics.Movie.decodeFile(Movie.java:59)
```

or

```
java.io.IOException: Mark has been invalidated.
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.reset(BufferedInputStream.java:350)
at android.graphics.Movie.decodeStream(Native Method)
```

I think it's a very simple error, but I can't get over it. Manifest has:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: You should test whether the download-and-save part is corrupting the file. After the app downloads the file, you can pull it off the emulator or device using `adb pull <cached_file_path> <local_file>`. Then you can check whether it's exactly what's on the server.

Comment: I pulled it off emulator, and it's fine. Image is 13kB if that somehow is important

Comment: Have you tried `Movie.decodeFile(new File(context.getCacheDir(), "mygif.gif").getAbsolutePath())`?

Comment: It doesn't help, I still get the error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

suggestion:

1.try move the download location to another folder like: `sdcard`, or the app another folder except the `cache`.

2.when init the `inputstream`, try use: init with a buffer size

```
int buffersize = 16*1024;
InputStream  is = new BufferedInputStream(xxx,buffersize);
```

3.to check the file existed in your folder

update: change the code like this and dont use `Movie.decodeFile`

```
 InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(getCacheDir(), "mygif.gif")), 16 * 1024);
        is.mark(16 * 1024); 
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
movie = Movie.decodeStream(is);
```

no exception throw, and the `movie` is not null.

Also, although your code will throw the exception, the `movie` is also not null.

Comment: 1. No difference; 2. No difference; 3. It exists and isn't corrupt

Comment: Thank you, the code below does the job! mark() was missing. Thanks a lot

Comment: This works good! But I'm wondering why to set the buffer size and mark the limit?

Comment: It works for some devices. But it doesn't work on Samsung Galaxy S3.

Answer (score 2):

I know is a really old post, but I was having the same issue

Copying the InputStream to a byte array and calling Movie.decodeByteArray worked for me, even on Samsung Devices

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based on the BeNeXuS's answer.

The file size may not always be known, see:

```
File file = ...;
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
```

or

```
InputStream inputStream = getContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```

After getting the inputStream:

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
int len;
while ((len = bis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) > 0) {
    baos.write(buffer, 0, len);
}
bis.close();

byte[] imageData = baos.toByteArray();
baos.close();

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Android up to 4.4 fails to decode Movie from File and Stream in case of  internal IOException in InputStream.reset() method. But decoding from bytes works well on all versions of Android. Here is quite minimal version of code to do this:

```
int size = (int) imageFile.length();
byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(imageFile);
int readLength = inputStream.read(buffer);
inputStream.close();
Movie movie = Movie.decodeByteArray(buffer, 0, readLength);
```