# How to open .gif file as InputStream from external storage on android

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I am trying to load .gif image from external storage (pictures directory) but I am getting **'file not found exception'** using the following code.

```
    InputStream mInputStream = null;
    AssetManager assetManager = getResources().getAssets();
    try {
        mInputStream = assetManager.open(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath().concat("/01.gif"));          

    } catch (IOException e) {           
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have also tested using manually path but got same exception

```
mInputStream = assetManager.open("file:///mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.shurjo.downloader/files/Pictures/01.gif");
```

There is a write/read permission from the SD card in menifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Please help me how can I open a file as InputStream from external storage. Thanks in advance.

**Note:** I have tested it on emulator and there is a file 01.gif under Pictures folder (please see manual path). I can create directories and put files in those directories but can not able to access those files though Input Stream.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6263235/940096) answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`AssetManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) is for accessing the files in the *assets* folder of the application package. It cannot be used to access files in the external storage.

You can use the following:

```
final String TAG = "MyAppTag";

File picturesDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
File imageFile = null;
final int readLimit = 16 * 1024;
if(picturesDir != null){
    imageFile = new File(picturesDir, "01.gif");
} else {
    Log.w(TAG, "DIRECTORY_PICTURES is not available!");
}
if(imageFile != null){
    mInputStream =  new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(imageFile), readLimit);
    mInputStream.mark(readLimit);
} else {
    Log.w(TAG, "GIF image is not available!");
}
```

Please also take a look at the sample code available in [`getExternalFilesDir`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29)

Update from : [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10240042/1321873)

Comment: How can I access files those are in external storage?

Comment: I want to like mInputStream = getAssets().open("07.gif"); that display the image on onDraw(). but above answer give InputSteam that does not show on view.

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: I am getting 'divided by zero' exception i.e mMovie.duration(); gives me 0 value where  Movie mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(mInputStream);

Comment: I have updated the answer to include debug information to help point out the problem. You should also take a look at the documentation to figure out how to use the APIs.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11913/discussion-between-rafiq-and-rajesh)