# In Android 10, Picasso is able to truly display an image with the Uri of the image without any permission but openInputStream requires permission

Tags: android, scoped-storage

In an Android application,
And **Android 10** regarding **Scoped Storage**,

**Picasso** is able to truly display an image with the **Uri** of an image
And it does not require any permission even if the versin of Android is 10
But when I try to use `openInputStream`, an error occurs which indicates permission is not granted

I wonder how **Picasso** can display the image without any permission but opening stream requires permission

The code is as following:

```
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(mUri).resize(200, 200).into(mImageButton);

        InputStream mInputStream;
        try
        {
            mInputStream = mContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(mUri);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And the error is as following:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.miui.gallery.provider.GalleryOpenProvider uri content://com.miui.gallery.open/raw/storage/emulated/0/Download/MellatMobileBank_Android.apk/icons/jar-gray.png from pid=2300, uid=10251 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()
```

Then, how can I have the stream of the image without granting permission?

**Edit:**
I did a test in `onActivityResult` where the image result could be retrieved from to see if the `openInputStream` works there or not
The code is as following:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == Constants.Uri_M) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri_M = data.getData();
                    Uri_M_String = Uri_M.toString();

                    mInputStream = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri_M);
```

Above code works fine while the following code has the same previous error (permission issue):

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == Constants.Uri_M) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri_M = data.getData();
                    Uri_M_String = Uri_M.toString();

                
                    Uri b = Uri.parse(Uri.decode(Uri_M_String));
                    mInputStream = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(b);
```

The point is Picasso is working fine with Uri_M_String but for `openInputStream` I first convert the `Uri_M_String` to `Uri_M` as following:

```
Uri Uri_M = Uri.parse(Uri.decode(Uri_M_String));
```

And then:

```
mInputStream = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri_M);
```

Which results in the error
So the problem is the conversion I'm doing to get the Uri from Uri string

But how can I reach the true Uri from its Uri string?

Comment: Where is the File referred by "mUri" located in the file system?

Comment: it is placed in GALLERY (External Storage)

Comment: Then you could probably use Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES, as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10811776/313870

Comment: Please start telling how you obtained that uri. After that tell at which moment you use Picasso or try to open an InputStream.

Comment: Uri.decode is creating the problem and without it there is no problem, I should find a workaround for Uri.decode