# IOException on Movie.decodeFile() - android

Tags: android, movie

I'm using below code. When executeing **Movie.decodeFile(pathName)** 
i got IOException.

```
Movie movie;
            File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();  
            File file = new File(dir,"weather.gif");

            String pathName = file.getAbsolutePath();
            Log.d("rvg", "Path: "+pathName);
            if(file.exists())
            {
                Log.d("rvg", "image available");
                movie=Movie.decodeFile(pathName);
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("rvg", "image not available");
            }
```

Logcat exception:

```
08-19 05:55:43.271: D/rvg(1458): Path: /mnt/sdcard/weather.gif
08-19 05:55:43.271: D/rvg(1458): image available
08-19 05:55:43.271: W/System.err(1458): java.io.IOException
08-19 05:55:43.271: W/System.err(1458):     at java.io.InputStream.reset(InputStream.java:218)
08-19 05:55:43.271: W/System.err(1458):     at android.graphics.Movie.decodeStream(Native Method)
08-19 05:55:43.271: W/System.err(1458):     at android.graphics.Movie.decodeTempStream(Movie.java:74)
08-19 05:55:43.271: W/System.err(1458):     at android.graphics.Movie.decodeFile(Movie.java:59)
08-19 05:55:43.271: W/System.err(1458):     at com.android.gif.GIFDemo$GIFView.<init>(GIFDemo.java:64)
08-19 05:55:43.271: W/System.err(1458):     at com.android.gif.GIFDemo$1.run(GIFDemo.java:36)
08-19 05:55:43.271: W/System.err(1458):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-19 05:55:43.271: W/System.err(1458):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-19 05:55:43.271: W/System.err(1458):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-19 05:55:43.271: W/System.err(1458):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
08-19 05:55:43.271: W/System.err(1458):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-19 05:55:43.271: W/System.err(1458):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-19 05:55:43.271: W/System.err(1458):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
08-19 05:55:43.271: W/System.err(1458):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-19 05:55:43.271: W/System.err(1458):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I want to load gif image from sdcard. How to solve this? If the gif image in drawable folder. its working well. But unable to load from sdcard. Give me the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **`InputStream`** with a **BufferSize** while loading **.GIF images** From **SDCARD**. It'll work for sure.

Follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240042/ioexception-cannot-load-file) for more Help.
Let me know if it's helped.